# Connect-PowerBiServiceAccount unable to connect with Service Principal

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I am using the MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt module for powershell to connect to Power BI so that I can upload a report, but am unable to get it to connect successfully. I have tried using this code on both a windows 10 enterprise machine and a mac running powershell core.
I am trying to connect using a service principal using the following code :

```
 $applicationId = "XXX"
$securePassword = "XXX" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $applicationId, $securePassword
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId "XXX"
```

I receive the following error

```
WARNING: (False) MSAL 4.25.0.0 MSAL.NetCore Darwin 20.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0: Sat May  8 05:10:33 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.121.3~9/RELEASE_X86_64 [11/15/2021 14:34:38 - 677c9e5e-9df6-4912-bdd3-994f59c64646] Fetching a new AT failed. Is AAD down? False. Is there an AT in the cache that is usable? False
    WARNING: (False) MSAL 4.25.0.0 MSAL.NetCore Darwin 20.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0: Sat May  8 05:10:33 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.121.3~9/RELEASE_X86_64 [11/15/2021 14:34:38 - 677c9e5e-9df6-4912-bdd3-994f59c64646] Either the exception does not indicate a problem with AAD or the token cache does not have an AT that is usable.
    WARNING: (False) MSAL 4.25.0.0 MSAL.NetCore Darwin 20.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0: Sat May  8 05:10:33 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.121.3~9/RELEASE_X86_64 [11/15/2021 14:34:38 - 677c9e5e-9df6-4912-bdd3-994f59c64646] Exception type: Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException
    , ErrorCode: invalid_client
    HTTP StatusCode 401
```

Comment: Hello @Steven,If my answer is helpful for you, you can upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested and it is working fine for me. I am getting the same error if I am using the some password for SecurePassword instead of client secret.

[image]

You can create your application Secret key Using New client secret.

[image]

```
$applicationId = "your application Client ID"
$securePassword = " application Cleint secret value " | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $applicationId, $securePassword
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount  -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId "Your tenant ID"
```

OutPut---
[image]